# Lone pairs in CHARMM for molecular dynamics

Tags: molecular-dynamics, charmm

I have a substrate that has a Br-C bond. In CHARRM the line below is included in the `.str` file:

`LONEPAIR COLI LP1    BR     C9     DIST 1.8900 SCAL 0.0`

I have also included coordinates for the lone pair in the `.pdb` file:

`ATOM     67  LP1 LIG     1       0.871  -0.147  -3.939  1.00  0.00      SUB`

I was able to solvate, minimize, and run dynamics on  the system. However, the lone pair does not move with the substrate, and the coordinates are not updated afterwards. This results in the lone pair being 4.5+ Å away from the bromine.

**My question is if this is normal, or is there something additional I need to include?** Please let me know if any additional details would be useful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which MD software are you using? Is it CHARMM or is it something else? From the question it's not clear if you referring to just the forcefield or the software as well.

Comment: I am using CHARMM for MD as well

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used CHRAMM before, other people in the site can probably help.

Comment: I don't know if it would help, but you may need to include more of the `.str` file. I haven't used CHARMM, but it looks like there are a [number of options](https://charmm-gui.org/charmmdoc/lonepair.html) for specifying lone pairs. Do you have any better luck with one of these other options?

Comment: Check if your PSF file contains "NUMLPH" section. If not, maybe you have built the system and added LONEPAIR in the topology file later. In this case, you may need to setup LONEPAIR in the CHARMM input (using LONEPAIR command) and write out to PSF file again.

Comment: @kskinnerx16 How are you doing with this question? Did you figure anything out over the last ~8  months? Were the comments by Tyberius or Sunhwan helpful?